# Xamarin Forms image binding on url with default on embedded resource

Tags: xaml, binding, xamarin.forms

i have a Xamarin ListView with images from internet. I would to show a default image (from embedded resource), and, when present, the image from an url.

I've tryied with this code but works only with UriImageSource, not for the embedded resource:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
                <Image>
                  <Image.Source>
                    <!-- does not works
                    <ImageSource>
       {utils:ImageResource Namespace.Assets.img-placeholder.png}
                    </ImageSource>
                    -->
                    <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding ImageUri}"></UriImageSource>
                  </Image.Source>
                </Image>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

if i use

```
<Image Source="{utils:ImageResource Namespace.Assets.img-placeholder.png}" />
```

this works showing the embedded resource default image

The model:

```
    public Uri ImageUri => Image != null ?
        new Uri($"http://www.example.com/{Image}")
        : null;
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**FFImageLoading**](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API) library.

According to its documentation:

> **LoadingPlaceholder**
>
> ImageSource property. If set, a loading placeholder is shown while
>   loading. It supports UriImageSource, FileImageSource and
>   StreamImageSource.
>
> **ErrorPlaceholder**
>
> ImageSource property. If set, if error occurs while loading image, an
>   error placeholder is shown. It supports UriImageSource,
>   FileImageSource and StreamImageSource.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to make it that complicated. From your viewmodel you simply provide a `string ImageUri` and bind it to `Image.Source`

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" />
```

this works for images from the web as well as resources, but they have to live in your platform projects. For Android you'll have to put them to `Resources\drawable` (or the respective folders for other resolutions) and set the build action to *AndroidResource*, for iOS to `Resources` (in different sizes with the `@2x`, `@3x` suffices, e.g. `img-placeholder@2x.png`) and set the build action to bundle resource. You can now set the placeholder from your viewmodel:

```
if(!HasRemoteImage(response))
{
    ImageUri = "img-placeholder.png";
}
```

Xamarin.Forms will create the `ImageSource` automatically for you.

One main advantage over resources you load directly is, that you don't have to care which image is the right one for the current resolution. Xamarin/Xamarin.Forms does that automatically for you.

Comment: I would to avoid the Android / Ios resources, i would to use the shared library embedded resource. Would it be possible?

Comment: You could (but this does not mean that I'd recommend this) load the resource with `Assembly.LoadManifestResourceStream` and then create a `StreamImageSource` from that stream, but I don't know if there is any way you can use the resource file with a `UriImageSource`